# Evaluating if a user has physically used their computer

Tags: windows, security

Trying to generate campus building occupancy statistics and exploring relying on computer activity data to do so.

Approach has been to use log activity (local Windows logs or EDR logs) and check for events that correspond with a human initiating that activity at the local keyboard.  We then filter out IP's that don't correspond with our local LAN.  Altogether, the thought is this will weed out remote users or remote users RDP'ing into a machine in their office at work.

Events/codes we've been looking for (Windows):

- Interactive logins (code 2)
- Cached interactive logins (code 11)
- Unlock (code 7)
- Cached unlock (code 13)

The first two seem to correlate fairly well, but the last two occur so frequently, in some cases, that we're suspicious automated activity could be triggering them and there may actually be no human present.

Looking for thoughts on the logon codes we've chosen and whether or not there are potentially better ones, or an alternate approach (we're looking to avoid installing sensors, etc. but are otherwise open to almost any creative idea).

Comment: When Audit Failure logon event (4625) is registered with logon type = 7, this commonly means that either you made a typo when entering the password, or someone is trying to break into the computer.